# How to set the preferences to run PIG script in Eclipse?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

I downloaded and installed the pigpen plugin in my eclipse, i followed the steps from [this 
link](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigPen))

but it little bit confusing when I set the Pig's ConfigurationPath.

can anyone tell me **how to set the preferences to run the pig scripts in eclipse**. I tired but not worked properly.

Comment: I believe ConfigurationPath is either pig's conf folder or hadoop's conf folder

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Unix Box to run Eclipse? If the answer is yes, then you can get it to work.If you are working on Windows and using a SSH client to connect to Unix box, I am afraid, it won't work (atleast as per the link mentioned in your post)